# how to edit checkout onepage login and create ? the ptml in where?

Tags: onepage-checkout

how to edit checkout onepage login and create ?

i dont know the ptml in where ? who can tell me how to edit

thank uuu

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should enable path hints in Admin panel. Select your current store in Current Configuration Scope . Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug. Set Template Path Hints to Yes and reload your frontend page. There you'll see all your paths.

Comment: Advanced -> Developer??in where 
just only have Disable Modules Output....=[

Comment: `Advanced` is referring to the name of the tab group, not the tab itself

Comment: Yes, you refer ro Advanced group -> Advanced tab. I refer to Advanced group -> Developer tab. It's right after Advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

On last version of Magento, after Magento 1.6 if I'm not wrong, they added a new feature called "Persistent cart", that affect the use of this phtml files on frontend. 
By default, this feature is active.

If it's your case, you can find the right phtml for these sections in:

../app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
../app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

instead of the classic:

../app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
../app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Then copy this files in your package folder, in /template directory, and you're done.

Comment: no no, it should be the `../app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml`, as @andy was asking about the form on the checkout page.

Comment: I have tried to modify, but did not work, still is default template, and when i delete the page still in here.why?

Comment: probably you are using a custom template which override the base template, or you have installed and enabled some kind of modules/extensions which defines a template other than the base one. If you are not sure where to find the correct file to edit, you should try the method suggested by @La Mi.

Comment: thank you ...but i dont know have a new file :loginformfallback ...i can edit in there now

Answer (score 0):

Magento default checkout login page is exits at

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.‌​
phtml.
```

if it not exit at the

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.‌​phtml
```